# ASP.NET Core won't run in IIS after upgrade to v1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've upgraded my project.json to use the new v1.1 of asp.net core and now when I try to start IIS Express to debug, I get the following errors:

> The program '[8784] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749
>   (0x80008083).
>
> The program '[7352] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code
>   0 (0x0).

My upgraded project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "7.1.10",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Maybe I am missing something in my project.json needed for the upgrade? Or one of the packages is not cooperating with v1.1? Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: When I change back to 1.0 everything runs fine.

Comment: pretty sure tools should be preview3

Comment: Did you intentionally _not_ update ASP.NET Core packages to 1.1.0? It might help to target 1.1.0 for all the packages in your project.json. Also, update IIS Integration Tools to `1.0.0-preview4-final`.

Comment: @HenkMollema, no that was not intentional. I think I may not fully understand how all of these version numbers work with eachother in the project.json file.  Are you saying I should update all "Microsoft.AspNetCore" references to "1.1.0" as well?

Comment: @big_water, yes that is what I mean. The .NET Core tooling (the `dotnet` command), the .NET Core runtime (the `netcoreapp1.1` target) and ASP.NET Core runtime packages have been updated.

Comment: @HenkMollema, I made the updates but still no luck and same error.  I've updated my project.json above.  Is there something I missed that you can see?  Thank you for your help

Comment: @HenkMollema, I was able to get it working with a few more updates.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of HenkMollema's comments and our friends at the Core team I was able to get this resolved.  Please see this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1827) for the answer.

The key was updating all of the packages as suggested to reference 1.1.0, or their appropriate updated package version for 1.1.0.  The table in the github link above lists the proper references for all packages that were updated in the v1.1 release.

I also installed the v1.1 SDK and Runtime available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).

Comment: You don't need the SDK, you just need the 1.1 Runtime installed. I had the same issue :).

Comment: @SledgeHammer, thanks for the clarification! I wasn't sure on that claim

Comment: I got the same upgrading all packages to 1.1. However I just installed 1.1 SDK and it started. Thanks.

Comment: For us it was that the .NET 1.1 Runtime was missing, and Visual Studio/dotnet wasn't giving an reasonable error message.