# EFCore throws System.InvalidOperationException when trying to attach non-tracked entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

My data context has the automatic tracking turned off in the creation of the context to prevent unnecessary tracking.  However, when I try to turn on tracking for an entry that has already been retrieved, an exception is thrown.  If I get the entry with .AsTracking() appended, the problem goes away.

Am I doing something wrong?

This doesn't work:

```
var biz = (from br in _context.BusinessRenewals where br.ACCOUNT == Account select br).First();

biz.EMAIL_ADDRESS = Email;
biz.WEB_SITE = WebSite;
_context.Update(biz);
```

This does work:

```
var biz = (from br in _context.BusinessRenewals where br.ACCOUNT == Account select br).AsTracking().First();

biz.EMAIL_ADDRESS = Email;
biz.WEB_SITE = WebSite;
_context.Update(biz);
```

What I want is this to work, but it gets a non-tracked entry so it doesn't work:

```
var biz = GetBusinessRenewal(Account);
biz.EMAIL_ADDRESS = Email;
biz.WEB_SITE = WebSite;
_context.Update(biz);
```

The exception I'm getting is:

> ### System.InvalidOperationException
>
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The instance of entity type 'BusinessRenewal' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

I'm using EFCore 1.0.1, ASP.Net Core 1.0.1, VS2015

Now using EFCore 1.1.0 and ASP.Net Core 1.1.0

Comment: can you attach the 2 models involved... Pretty sure it's a State issue, meaning one state doesn't need modification but the other does.

Comment: @mvermef: What models are you referring to?  I'm only using one model.  The BusinessRenewals entity has navigation properties to three other entities. However, both statements are accessing the BusinessRenewals entity in the same way with the only difference being the tracking.

Comment: @mvermef: Also, when I examined the state for the non-tracked entries, it was "detached" which is what I expected.  When I used either the Attach or Update methods, the exception was thrown.

Comment: Try to upgrade to 1.1.0 first please.

Comment: After updating to 1.1.0 and resolving dependencies from other packages, the application does not run.  The output is:`The program '[17016] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[4268] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: What a mess.  Tried to upgrade to 1.1.0 and now the application won't work. Frustrating.

Comment: OK. I was able to get it running after using the advice in this post: [ASP.NET Core won't run in IIS after upgrade to v1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663088/asp-net-core-wont-run-in-iis-after-upgrade-to-v1-1/40663860)  After getting it to run again, the problem still occurs.  Now using EFCore 1.1 and ASP.Net Core 1.1.

Comment: @GertArnold OK. I upgraded to 1.1.0, but the results are the same.

Comment: What I ended up doing to get around the error was to put an optional parameter on my method that gets the entry to indicate whether or not to track the entry.  Not ideal, but it fixed the problem I was having and I can get the entry in only one method.